# how to setup android ndk in wsl2?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo, wsl-2

I just shifted from windows to wsl2 for android build

Now when I ran this command
`eas build -p android --local`

I first faced Android SDK location issue, I fixed it by giving this path
`/mnt/c/Users/Username/AppData/local/android/sdk`

Then I got this error
`[RUN_GRADLEW] [CXX1416] Could not find Ninja on PATH or in SDK CMake bin folders.`
I fixed that using `sudo apt install ninja-build`

Now I get this error
`[RUN_GRADLEW] Script '/tmp/sc0rp10n/eas-build-local-nodejs/37c02321-6100-4ee5-93b3-e8bbd3b0d857/build/node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking/scripts/android/autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 326`
I am not sure how to fix this issue now.

Please help